# Is there an object of type boolean in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, boolean

I want to use a property that is nonatomic and weak but I can't use BOOL because it isn't an object. What is ios/objective-c's equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the property to `assign` instead of `weak` for a non-object type such as `BOOL`.

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isValid;
```

Comment: Or one can use an NSNumber object containing a bool value.  But care needs to be taken with that to set/query it properly -- it cannot be used in a logical expression without explicitly extracting the value.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Wood is correct (you probably want to use `assign` with `BOOL`).

You *could* use `NSNumber`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNumber *isValidNumber;

// …

BOOL number = @(YES);
self.isValidNumber = number;

// …

if (self.isValidNumber.boolValue) {
    // something is valid
}
```

However, `isValidNumber` would become `nil` when the method returns (because there are no more `strong` pointers to it). So it's not clear *why* you'd want to do this.